# Why is my lobster bisque white?

Tags: soup, seafood, reduction, lobster

I cooked a few living Atlantic lobsters in water for 2-3 minutes. Before cooking they were bluish, after cooking red, as normal. I halved and fried them in butter, the served them. We had a bucket with ice and water on the table, where we discarded the shells and left them overnight. Next morning, there was still lots of ice left in the water. I took the whole bucket and started cooking it to make a bisque, adding only a few bay leaves and celery. After cooking a few hours, I started reducing it. In my experience, this should turn out an orange coloured sort of reduction. However, this one became totally white! It looks like milk, but tastes like lobster. Can anyone explain this? Is it safe to consume?

Comment: How does this question have 6 upvotes and no answers?